# What Path is Magento Connect Trying to Change To After Login?

Tags: magento

At every turn, I get the error message: “Deployment FTP Error. Cannot chdir after login to:”

I successfully did my first time through connection and setup by chmod’ing my /{complete_path_to_magento_installation_dir}/**downloader**/ to 0777

a cache.cfg file got created in /downloader/

a connect.cfg file got created in /downloader/

I then chmod’ed /{complete_path_to_magento_installation_dir}/**downloader**/ back to 0755

My Magento Installation Absolute Path is: **/home/abcde/public_html/magento/**

My Host’s Document Root is: **/home/abcde/public_html/**

My Magento Connect Directories Live at: **/home/abcde/public_html/magento/downloader/**

Here are my settings:

Magento Connect Channel Protocol: **Ftp**

Preferred State: **Stable**

Use custom permissions: **No**

Deployment Type: **FTP Connection**

FTP Host: **ftp://{mydomain.com}/**

FTP Login: **my ftp userid**

FTP Password: **my ftp password**

Finally, when Installation Path: is set to (see list below) I get the error message(s):

Installation Path: **{I left it blank}** Error Message: Unable to read saved settings. Please check Installation Path of FTP Connection.

Installation Path: **/** Error Message: Unable to read saved settings. Please check Installation Path of FTP Connection.

Installation Path: **/home/** Error Message: Deployment FTP Error. Cannot chdir after login to: /home/

Installation Path: **/home/abcde/** Error Message: Deployment FTP Error. Cannot chdir after login to: /home/abcde/

Installation Path: **/home/abcde/public_html/** Error Message: Deployment FTP Error. Cannot chdir after login to: /home/abcde/public_html/

Installation Path: **/home/abcde/public_html/magento/** Error Message: Deployment FTP Error. Cannot chdir after login to: /home/abcde/public_html/magento/

Installation Path: **/home/abcde/public_html/magento/downloader/** Error Message: Deployment FTP Error. Cannot chdir after login to: /home/abcde/public_html/magento/downloader/

Installation Path: **magento** Error Message: Deployment FTP Error. Cannot chdir after login to: /magento/

Does anyone know the secret to Magento Connect Settings?

Thanks.

Comment: Haha, this is question #13431343 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431343/what-path-is-magento-connect-trying-to-change-to-after-login

Comment: Your link reverts right back to my question @PicklishDoorknob. Did you provide the wrong link?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. This is question #13431343 :P

Comment: Oh, you had me excited for an answer. Enjoy surfing @PicklishDoorknob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue that I was able to fix using

from the /usr/share/nginx folder

double checked that nginx runs as nginx.

1. chowned everything to nginx.
2. chmoded directories to 775  (Has to have group write privlages)
3. chmoded files to 644

Commands:

```
sudo find . -exec chown nginx {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

from the /usr/share/nginx/html folder

```
sudo chmod -R o+w media var skin downloader 
sudo chmod o+w app/etc
```

The same should work for apache, just chown everything to apache or noname depending on how apache is setup.

Comment: After going through the many posts, this is the one worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

This problem lied with the Installation Path for me. For example: My site was installed on a subdomain, but the FTP user had access to the main domain and subdomains. Therefore, when it connected it needed an initial directory of "magneto" (my subdomain for this install).

I would FTP into your site (with no initial directory set in your FTP client) and make note of which folders you navigate into. That should work in many cases, although it could vary host to host.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem was experienced by me :
I resolved it by doing the following changes:

777 ---------> /downloader folder
777 ----------> /var folder
777 ----------> /media folder

disabled cache
flush cache
flushed javascript,images and all other mentioned cache.

Kept installation path empty or u can add `/`
Hopes this helps you.
Good Luck.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it @Nikhil_K_R -- thanks. It is both odd and concerning to me however. (1) The FTP user ID I am logging into Magento Connect with is the same user id I installed Magento with. Thus, it is the owner of all the directories. Hence it gets *7** privileges as a result and can write to those directories. Now if the web user is somehow coming into play (in my case "nobody") then I can see why the permissions would be an issue, but I was of the impression that Magento Connect Manager was using my FTP id to login. (2) Isn't making all those directors 0777 world-writable a security issue?

Comment: No success. Here's what I did @Nikhil_K_R: (1) I chmod'ed /downloader and /media and /var to 0777. (2) I disabled cache. (3) I flushed all 4 cache areas. (4) I tried with path empty and with path "/". In both cases I got `Unable to read saved settings. Please check Installation Path of FTP Connection.` error message

Answer (score 0):

Just put the path as "/" and it should work.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I also had to unserialize the connect.cfg file, update the FTP path manually, serialize it, then save the connect.cfg file again before it would work. It wouldn't accept the values I was posting in the form on the Downloader.