# Magento - Unable to write to the configuration file - tried almost everything

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Trying to upgrade from Magento 1.9.3.3 to 1.9.3.4

but I was able to login, going through some help I made couple of changes and finally renamed the folder `downloader` and uploaded a freash `downloader` folder to `Magento` site root.
But I am getting error
`Unable to write to the configuration file.`

1. I have also changed to folder permission for `downloader` to 777.
2. The file `cache.cfg` and `connect.cfg` are created in `downloader` folder.
3. The file created `cache.cfg` and `connect.cfg` created are owned by root.

but the error still persists. I am unable to login to Magento connect Manager with the correct admin password.

What I am still missing? I have run out of options.
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

What I am still missing

Comment: what about the sub-directories permissions?

Comment: Are you running your web server as root? Normally it will run as a specific user, e.g. "apache" or "nginx". If that's the case then the cache and config files you mention being owned as root will mean that those users do not have sufficient privileges to access them. Try `chown` (changing ownership) to the web server's user.

Comment: @RobbieAverill - you are right, when I remove cache and connect files, it is being recreated owned by apache and not web user. but even if I change the ownership to web user, the problem still persists.

Comment: .htaccess issue?

Comment: Perhaps Brad's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431343/what-path-is-magento-connect-trying-to-change-to-after-login will help you.  Worked for me.